# Firebug kills -webkit Settings in CSS File - Why?

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, firebug

**style.css** - *Original File*

```
.box { -webkit-border-radius:8px; -moz-border-radius:8px; padding:10px;  }
```

**style.css** - *In Firebug CSS Console*

```
.box { -moz-border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px; padding:10px;  }
```

**How can I force Firebug to show my -webkit css styles as well?**
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can - the correct behaviour for browsers is to ignore style rules they don't understand. Firefox sees `-webkit-xxx` and effectively removes it from the style set, so it can't ever be applied to `.box`.

Safari's inspector will show the `-webkit-` rules but ignore the `-moz-` rules for the same reason.

Comment: Interestingly, webkit's inspector now allows you to see other vendor-specific rules - `-moz-xxx` and `-ms-xxx`. It doesn't apply the styles, and flag them as 'not understood', but you can see how the selectors are matched to elements, which can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug handles only Gecko's **native rules** (styles). Gecko is a browser engine, used in Firefox (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko).

-webkit is used by another browser engine, so it is ignored.
similar to `-ms` ("Trident" engine - IE8), `-o` (Presto - Opera), or `-khtml` (KHTML - Konqueror).