# firebug not shows  browser specific css declarations. 

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Firebug kills -webkit Settings in CSS File - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808146/firebug-kills-webkit-settings-in-css-file-why)

firebug shows me, in firefox:

```css
.boxShadow {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #000;
}
```

original css declarations:

```css
.boxShadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #000;
}
```

how can i dislay selected element's browser specific css declarations in firebug ?

Chrome Inspector do it right.

## Firebug

[image: firefox]

## Chrome Inspector

[image: chorme]

Comment: Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808146/firebug-kills-webkit-settings-in-css-file-why

Comment: I read that question but I just want to see !!selected element's!! orginal css declarations not edit -vendor specific rules. google-chorme inspector shows me all of original css declaration. i think firebug can do that.

Comment: That bug that I posted previously ([here](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4210)) was related to that. According to the documentation, the source edit option "displays the CSS as it came from the CSS source including its formatting, comments etc." However, in my machine that doesn't happen. So I think that the bug is back again. BTW: I'm using version 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering engine cannot process these rules and they are therefore discarded, as any other invalid rule would be. Even if they were accessible, they would not contribute to an element's rendering and yo would not be able to confirm their validity or calculated values.